# Can $\int_{-4}^{-2}{\mathrm{cosec}^2x} dx $ be evaluated?

Tags: calculus, integration

Bostock and Chandler - Core Maths for Advanced Level states that:

$\int_{-4}^{-2}{(\mathrm{cosec}^2x)}dx = 1 $

It seems to me like the integral, $[-\cot x]_{-4}^{-2}$, would have a singularity at $\pi$ which would make this impossible to evaluate. Am I missing something obvious, or is the textbook incorrect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order the integral to be meaningful (under the most widespread conventions), the two limits
$$
\lim_{t\to -\pi^-}\int_{-4}^{t}\frac{1}{\sin^2x}\,dx
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
\lim_{t\to -\pi^+}\int_{t}^{-2}\frac{1}{\sin^2x}\,dx
$$
should exist and be finite.

Neither is finite.